# Cadena de texto y float en Html con Django con rstrip

Tags: html, python, django

en mi Html, le paso un context con todos los resultados de una base de datos, entre ellos, uno es el precio de artículos. 
Dentro de un bucle, lo muestro como **{{ a.precio }}**, tipo float. El problema es que algunos precios son por ejemplo 15.50 ó 20.00, y quiero quitar los ceros de la derecha.

En Python **str(precio).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')**, los deja como 15.50 y 20
Pero en el html, no consigo hacerlo, me indica que no se puede analizar;

```
{{ str(a.precio).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacer cualquier manipulaciónes con datos en plantillas de Django necessitas registrar tu propio filtros: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

1. Pon file `templatetags/precio.py`

```
app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        precio.py
    views.py
```

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='precio')
def precio(value):
    return str(value).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

2. Carga esto en la parte superior de la plantilla:

```
{% load precio %}
```

3. Utiliza como

```
{{ a.precio|precio }}
```

Comment: Mil gracias, Perfecto